# Formatting text only with CSS

Tags: css, text, formatting, styling

I run a site where users submit basic news articles. I want to add some formatting features for their submissions.

Is it possible to add custom formatting to text **only using CSS**?

For example, user can add:

```
**This should be bold**
```

And the text appears bold. Or user adds `>` at the beginning of the paragraph:

```
> This could be a lengthy paragraph
```

And the paragraph is aligned to the center.

Is such thing possible to do?

Comment: You're thinking of [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) and its variants, much like what's used here on StackOverflow and which was exploited in your very own question to highlight the text you posted. Thus, your question as to whether it's possible to do this seems a little strange.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible using pure CSS.
You have to use `Javascript` or `JQuery` or process your custom tags in `Server-Side` and render them as html and css as you want.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I have opened a question specifically using Javascript or jQuery: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25220102/formatting-text-using-custom-markdown-with-javascript-or-jquery

Answer (score 0):

No it is not. You will need javascript or php to replace `**` with `<b>` for example. Otherwise your users would need to put in `<b>Hello</b>`

Comment: Thank you. I will shortly open a question asking the same thing aimed at Javascript.