# Formatting text using custom markdown with Javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, formatting

I run a site where users submit basic news articles. I want to add some formatting features for their submissions, quite similar to the markdown feature used here.

For example, user can add:

```
**This should be bold**
```

And the text appears bold. Or user adds `>` at the beginning of the paragraph:

```
> This could be a lengthy paragraph
```

And the paragraph gets wrapped in `<blockquote>`.

Note that I do not want it to be processed server-side.

How can I do this using Javascript or jQuery?

EDIT:

I found a way to make text within astericks bold using the following:

```
<div class="content">The following will be bold: **I am bold**</div>
```

jQuery:

```
function markdown(markdownable) {

var bold = /\*\*(\S(.*?\S)?)\*\*/gm;
    markdownable = markdownable.replace( bold, '<span style="font-weight:bold">$1</span>' );

    return markdownable;
}

$('.content').each(function() {

    var markdownable = $(this).html(),
        content = markdown(markdownable);

    $(this).html(content);


});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dwxmjkb3/).

However, I still have no clue on how to make a paragraph starting with `>` wrapped into `<blockquote>`.

Comment: This is not a site for coding requests. You need to show a substantial attempt first.

Comment: @Anonymous Sure, I have added a solution for one of the formatting examples, it works, although haven't found a solution for the other example. With that being said though, I think my edit of this question qualifies as a "substantial attempt", do you agree?

Comment: This is really more of a place for debugging instead of asking how to do something.  So, yes, it was a substantial attempt for the first problem, but if that problem has already been solved, it is best to show the attempt for the other problem.

Comment: @Anonymous There are no attempt for the second problem because I genuinely do not know how to approach it. Surely there are other questions on this platform asking questions without providing code.

Answer (score 0):

The Markdown solution that Reddit uses is freely available, lightweight, well documented and does everything you asked for and more:

http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this pluggin [markitUp!](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/examples/markdown/)

markItUp! is a JavaScript plugin built on the jQuery library. It allows you to turn any textarea into a markup editor. Html, Textile, Wiki Syntax, Markdown, BBcode or even your own Markup system can be easily implemented.

Hope this will help you.